Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function
Good morning.
On August 26th of this year, I published a version of an app built with React-Native. Everything went smoothly, and the internal test reports sent by the store did not show any issues. However, on September 27th, when launching a new version, Google Play Console reported undefined is not a function error for the following devices below.

Since I do not have these devices physically, I downloaded emulators for the specified Android versions and ran the app natively, using the Android folder. However, I was unable to replicate the issue.
I searched through every part of the code for something that could be causing the problem, but I couldn’t find anything wrong.
I then began to suspect that the issue might not lie in my logic. So, I decided to remove all logic entirely. The only change made was updating the project version; everything else was exactly the same as the stable version from August 26th, including the files package-lock.json, package.json, and yarn.lock.
To publish the app, I executed the command cd android && ./gradlew clean to clean all the build files in the Android folder. Then, I deleted the entire node_modules folder and regenerated it to ensure there were no corrupted packages. After that, I ran the command ./gradlew bundleRelease to generate the package in AppBundle format for release.
And guess what: the stable version, which had not reported any problems when published on August 26th, now presented the same issue: undefined is not a function.
I updated the packages using yarn upgrade, but the error still persisted.
I’ve read every type of forum about this issue, but most of them stated it was a code error. Unfortunately, I no longer know how to proceed. How is it possible for a version with the same code to start showing issues out of nowhere, especially when no errors were detected in the pre-launch report the first time it was published?
Below is the error reported by the Play Console.
Exception com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in App
    in Router
    in RouterComponent
    in Connect(RouterComponent)
    in Provider
    in App
    in RCTView
    in Unknown
    in AppContainer, js engine: hermes, stack:
componentWillUnmount@1:738353
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410510
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410734
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410547
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410734
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:411109
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410734
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410547
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410887
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410734
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:411109
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:410734
recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects@1:410175
commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber@1:411109
recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects@1:411649
commitMutationEffectsOnFiber@1:413289
commitRootImpl@1:422844
commitRoot@1:422442
flushSyncWorkAcrossRoots_impl@1:376999
scheduleUpdateOnFiber@1:418005
updateContainer@1:427141
unmountComponentAtNode@1:427427
anonymous@1:436470
unmountComponentAtNodeAndRemoveContainer@1:108229
unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag@1:339749
__callFunction@1:97578
anonymous@1:96018
__guard@1:96959
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@1:95976
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:146)
  at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:240)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:233)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)

I am extremely grateful to anyone who can help me.

May be it helps you - recently I have make some changes in my app and after submitting in stores I got similar error - undefined is not a function.
It runs on a device after updating (one - two times) while updates are running
In my case "undefined is not a function" was function placed outside a component which I render:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/H8c6G5Oy.png
